# Pip installed (and updated), but can't be found

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, command-prompt

I've installed Python (3.9.5) and pip (22.0.3), but pip can't be found with the cmd prompt:

```
C:\> py --version
Python 3.9.5
C:\> pip --version
Der Befehl "pip" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

This is the path to the pip files: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts.
And this is the path to Python 3.9: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

Also, I tried adding the directory to Python39\Scripts to PATH:

```
C:\>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts"
ERFOLGREICH: Angegebener Wert wurde gespeichert.
C:\>
```

However, pip still can't be found.

I also tried this (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows), but it didn't work:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file get-pip.py: Permission denied
  0 2548k    0  9597    0     0   160k      0  0:00:15 --:--:--  0:00:15  164k
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

I'm completely lost here, could it be that my directories are messed up and that's why I can't find pip?

I'd be grateful for any help I can get!

Comment: `python -m pip` works?. If not could be that pip is not installed in your machine

Comment: That or `py -m pip`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try calling pip through python instead:

```sh
py -m pip --version
```

or

```sh
python3 -m pip --version
```

or

```sh
python -m pip --version
```